# css span tag height sort

Tags: html, css

hello i want to this span tags sort in one line

but tag that has inner text is sort down, tag that has no inner

text is sort up

so these tags height is not correct

I want to sort this span box(class==a) in one line

what is the solution?

sample code is in bottom

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <title>a</title>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <style>
    .a {
        width: 17%;
        height: 5%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <span  class = "a"></span>
      <span  class = "a">2</span>
      <span  class = "a">2</span>
      <span  class = "a">2</span>
      <span  class = "a">2</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is in 1 line, what are you trying to do ? and Height in % will only apply if container has a fix height. To have all your `a` with same height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) If you define `height` with a percentage value, the parent element needs a defined height. Below I defined 100% height for `body` (the direct parent) and `html`the parent of `body`). If this is inside a `div`, that `div` needs a height definition.

2.) To align inline-blocks by their top border, you can use `vertical-align: top;` (The default is `baseline` otherwise)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
}

.a {
  width: 17%;
  height: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="a"></span>
  <span class="a">2</span>
  <span class="a">2</span>
  <span class="a">2</span>
  <span class="a">2</span>
</body>
```